# getServerSideProps Error serializing when return boolean value

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm getting the error below, when I use the getServerSideProps function to return within the props timeline, just a Boolean value.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  const id = params.id;
  const timeline = await verifyTimelineID(id);

  return {
    props: {
      timeline,
    },
  };
}
```

My function only returns if there is that event with the sent id and it returns true or false.

```
export async function verifyTimelineID(id) {
  axios
    .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/events/${id}`)
    .then(() => {
      return { exists: true };
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return { exists: false };
    });
}
```

error output:

```
Error: Error serializing `.timeline` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/timeline/[id]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try returning the value from the verifyTimelineID and edit it a bit like this.

```
export async function verifyTimelineID(id) {
  return axios
    .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/events/${id}`)
    .then(() => {
      return { exists: true };
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return { exists: false };
    });
}
```

Also I think it's a bit better to use async await here like the following.

```
export async function verifyTimelineID(id) {
    try {
        await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/events/${id}`)
        return { exists: true };
    } catch(e) {
        return { exists: false };
    }
}
```

I think it's a cleaner, better syntax

Comment: Thanx, much better and clean